# There is no column named id5093 in the table body_record. It is ignored for this operation

Tags: sql-server-2012

One of our Database - has been Error Spamming Event Logs for over 8 months stating the below Error:

> There is no column named id5093 in the table body_record. It is ignored for this operation.

The Column has been removed and re-added, the DB also has been refreshed/restarted, but we still keep getting the Error even though the Column exists.

Below code was used:

```
Use OM2;
alter table body_record add id5093 nvarchar(max);
```

Is there a way to fix this please?

Comment: What is the operation, in which "It is ignored for this operation." message is produced? View, procedure, etc.? Try to refresh its plan.

Comment: Could it be a stale ORM cache? Please edit the question to include the actual SQL statement that produces this error. Off hand it doesn't sound like it originates in SQL Server.

Comment: @MichaelGreen - Thanks for your reply. You are right it is not in SQL Error Logs rather Application Logs in Event Viewer.

Comment: @Akina - Many thanks. There is an exception list not to store any value into this column, configured into the Registry. it is expected to have NULLs in the column. I will give the plan refresh a try. As it is a LIVE system, I am quite hesitant to interrupt any I/Os